# Boolean in jQuery POST to MVC5 Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using jQuery to post some data to an ActionMethod on an MVC 5 controller. When one of the parameters is `true`, everything works, but when it's `false`, I get a 404.

This works fine (HTTP 200)

```
var data =  { userId: userId, approve: true, reason: 'Unaccepted'};
$.post('approve-user', data, function (response) {
...
```

This results in a 404

```
var data =  { userId: userId, approve: false, reason: 'Unaccepted'};
$.post('approve-user', data, function (response) {
...
```

My Action Method has this signature:

```
[POST("approve-user")]
public async Task<JsonResult> ApproveOrRejectPost(int userId, bool approve, string reason) {
```

I thought there might be a quirk with converting the JS boolean to something .NET could understand, but the same happens if I use a string in the method signature instead. The only thing which causes it to fail seems to be that middle boolean variable.

Comment: You can try this `public async Task<JsonResult> ApproveOrRejectPost(int userId, Func<bool> approve, string reason) {`

Comment: 404 suggests that the URL is wrong. What are the URLs for the two requests?

Comment: wow, weird behaviour but you may try pass a number instead of a bool; `0` for false and `1` for true.

Comment: The URL for both is the same in Firebug, it's only that one parameter which  is different.

Comment: Using an integer in JavaScript also results in a 404 if the value of approve is `0` or `1`.

Comment: Cannot duplicate this at all - and the route values have nothing to do with getting a `404`. Ensure your url is correctly generated using `url = '@Url.Action()`

Comment: And what is your `[POST("approve-user")]` attribute (that is not part of MVC)?

Answer (score 1):

i think maybe the position of bool is making the issue  i am not sure but i can suggest you a quick fix since ts showing 404 error this means your action cannot be found when bool value is false

try this in your action

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ApproveOrRejectPost(int userId, bool approve = false, string reason) {
```

even though also try to swap the parameters like in both client and server side
and check the result

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ApproveOrRejectPost(int userId, string reason, bool approve) {
```

Comment: I've tried moving the boolean to the end and making it optional, but still get a 404 when the boolean is false.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might just be down to the way MVC is deserializing the data you send. `approve` being false may just be getting omitted from data sent on the wire. The reason I say this is because the router cannot resolve a method **without** `approve` in the action signature, so it returns a 404 (NotFound). I'm not entirely sure though. Add the same action with `approve` removed from the signature and see what happens :)

To solve this though, I think this might help you:

I would recommend creating an object that models your incoming data:

```
public class ApprovalMetadata
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public bool approve { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this object in your action like so:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ApproveOrRejectPost([FromBody] ApprovalMetadata data)
{
    ...
}
```

`[FromBody]` deserializes the JSON in the incoming *body* that you sent, into the `ApprovalMetadata` object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Same result. I also tried making the boolean nullable. This is what Firebug sends: https://i.imgur.com/Jq0KF6w.png

Comment: If you're getting data through with `approve: false`(per the screenshot you've linked) that means you're no longer getting a 404. Was that not problem you were getting?

Please let me know if I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: The screenshot shows the request, not the response. The server responds with a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this had something to do with a conflict between the AttributeRouting package for MVC4 and the built in attribute routing in MVC5. The app was updated from MVC4 but the older attribute routing library was still used. Tearing it out and replacing with MVC5's inbuilt attribute routing solved the problem.

Thanks @Ahmed Zaman for a novel approach to accepting POST data in controllers.